# Insert space between h:panelGrid rows

Tags: css, jsf-2, panelgrid

**Versions :**

Aapche MyFaces 2.1.14

RichFaces 4.3.5

**Issue :**

I am facing an issue to insert space between rows of h:panelGid.  Below is the general layout for the page :

```
User Id :   <empty space>
<INPUT-BOX>     <empty space>

<!-- space here -->

Password 1  :   <empty space>
<INPUT-BOX>     Description Text

<!-- space here -->

Password 2  :   <empty space>
<INPUT-BOX>     Description Text
```

To get above layout , i have used below code. Each inner panel grid holds 4 elements in two columns. 
Top panel grid wraps all inner panel grids with column as 1.

The issue is , I am not able to get space betwen two inner panel grids or more specifically between table cells. 
I have tried using :

1)cellspacing

2)rowClasses

But none of the two approches are working. The style used for rowClasses is given below. 
When debugged through browser , it seems that `rowClasses` does get applied to each `<tr>` of table.

Can anybody please help ?

**Code :**

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" rowClasses="tableCell,tableCell,tableCell,tableCell" cellspacing="100px">


        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="User ID:" styleClass="label"/>
                <h:outputText value=""/>

                <h:inputText id="userid" name="userid" styleClass="input"/>
                <h:outputText value=""/>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <!-- space here --> 


        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Password1:" styleClass="label"/>
                <h:outputText value=""/>

                <h:inputText id="passwd1" name="passwd1" styleClass="input"/>
                <h:outputText  value="This is password 1"/>

        </h:panelGrid>

        <!-- space here --> 
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Password2:"/>
                <h:outputText value=""/>

                <h:inputText id="passwd2" name="passwd2" styleClass="input"/>
                <h:outputText value="This is password 2 ."/>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <!-- space here --> 

        <h:commandButton id="submit" styleClass="button" value="Submit" action="#{bean.action}"/>


</h:panelGrid>

<!-- style -->

.tableCell{
    margin-top : 100px;
}
```

Comment: Until you have only 1 column in `h:panelGrid`, you can add <br /> or empty image as space (for example: `<h:graphicImage value="/images/spacer.gif" height="5" />`). **Not related:** I recommend you to change outer `h:panelGrid` to columns="2" and remove all inner `h:panelGrid`(s) (and put `h:commandButton` into `<f:facet name="footer">`). After that you will need add something in second column (for example `<h:outputText value="" />`) too.

Comment: A `<p:separator/>` creates a horisontal line. `<p:separator style="visibility: hidden"/>` creates a bit of horisontal space. Height can be styled too. I don't know if it works where you need it, but give it a try

Comment: Thanks Vasil for your reply. Adding h:graphicImage worked . Thanks for the same . Adding no break space character within h:outputText also works. About "Not Related Part" , is there any reason apart from more simple layout to change h:panelGrid to 2 columns ? Also is there any advantage in putting commandButton in f:facet footer ?                                                    @Jaqen : The h:graphicImage creates the same effect as separator.